# Python cannot import CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am currently learning Pandas for data analysis and having some issues reading a csv file in Jupyter Notebook editor.

When I am running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\PythonHow\nycrime.csv")
```

I get an error message, which ends with

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\\PythonHow\nycrime.csv' does not exist
```

and it's full lenght:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-75f2b616e06c> in <module>()
----> 1 lf2 = pd.read_csv("C:\PythonHow\nycrime.csv")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
656 
657     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
403 
404     # Create the parser.
--> 405     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
406 
407     if chunksize or iterator:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
762             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
763 
--> 764         self._make_engine(self.engine)
765 
766     def close(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
983     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
984         if engine == 'c':
--> 985             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
986         else:
987             if engine == 'python':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1603         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1604 
-> 1605         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1606 
   1607         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:4209)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:8873)()

FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\\PythonHow\nycrime.csv' does not exist
```

obs.: the file is in the directory with this exact name

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here: `FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\\PythonHow\nycrime.csv' does not exist` the string `\n` is interpreted as a newline:

The workaround is:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\PythonHow\\nycrime.csv")
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\PythonHow\nycrime.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using relative paths, it's always preferred :

- more reliable / stable
- easier to debug
- easier to maintain
- easier to distribute

Code :

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want')
```

or

```
import os
path = os.getcwd() + '\relative\path\here.csv'
```

Also make sure whether your system uses `/`or `\`

That said, in your case, the error is probably due to the `\` that are special characters in python. To use your string as a raw string and disable the processing of these special characters please use `r"myPath"` instead of `"myPath"`

Comment: Please up and mark as answer if this issue is closed

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, adding two backward slashes also solves the issue. Also adding `'r'` before path will correct your path.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\\PythonHow\\nycrime.csv")
```